# ¿Doble click en un radio button para que se pueda ejecutar una función?

Tags: javascript, html, radiobutton

Tengo un radio button que esta dentro de una celda de una tabla, dicho radio button cuando le doy click debería ejecutar una función, el problema que tengo es que no ejecuta la función cuando le doy un click, sino cuando dos click, es decir; tengo que darle dos click al radio button para que se pueda ejecutar la función.

```js
   function mostrarcumple0(){
    var checks  = document.getElementsByClassName("cumple0");
    var checksnone = document.getElementsByClassName("cumplep0")
    for(var i=0; i<checks.length; i++){
        if(checks[i].style.display=="none"){
            checks[i].style.display="block";
        }else{
            checks[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }

    for(var j=0; j<checksnone.length; j++){
        if(checksnone[j].style.display=="block"){
            checksnone[j].style.display="none";
            checksnone[j].checked=false;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
    <td width="47">
       <div class="container">
        <input ng-if="$index==0" type="radio" id="radioNoC_@{{$index}}" onclick="mostrarcumple0()" name="estado_@{{$index}}" value="noCumple" ng-model="variable.noCSeleccionado">
       </div>
    </td>
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, si ejecutas el código en la pagina funciona correctamente, tal vez hay alguna otra cosa que hace que no se ejecute la función y que no esta en este código.

Comment: y porque no lo cambias a un checkbox, si esta marcado no cumple y si no esta marcado cumple , un radiobutton es para elegir una opcion y solo tienes una, el checkbox generalmente se usa como bandera puedes notarlo en todos las paginas que visitas

Comment: jackNavaRow en realidad tengo mas de una opción, pero solo puse una para no llenar esto de código.

Comment: ¿El primer click selecciona el radiobutton y el segundo abre la función, o es necesario doble click para ambas cosas?

Comment: Hola Carmen, ya pude encontrar la respuesta, gracias por tu interés.

Answer (score 0):

Ya puede encontrar el problema lo que pasa es que cuando se le da click al radio button si se ejecuta la función, pero no de la manera en que se espera. porque cuando entra en la función pregunta:

```
if(checks[i].style.display=="none"){
        checks[i].style.display="block";
    }else{
        checks[i].style.display="none";
    }
```

El problema esta en que en primera instancia el check no esta en "none" por lo tanto no se cumple el *if*, y entra en el *else* por lo tanto lo pone en "none", por tal razón hay que darle otro click para que ahora si se cumpla el *if* y por lo tanto se ponga en display block.

Por lo tanto lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
function mostrarcumple0(){
    var checks  = document.getElementsByClassName("cumple0");
    var checksnone = document.getElementsByClassName("cumplep0")
    for(var i=0; i<checks.length; i++){
        if(checks[i].style.display=="none"){
            checks[i].style.display="block";
        }else if(checks[i].style.display=="block"){
            checks[i].style.display="none";
        }else{
            checks[i].style.display="block";
        }
    }

    for(var j=0; j<checksnone.length; j++){
        if(checksnone[j].style.display=="block"){
            checksnone[j].style.display="none";
            checksnone[j].checked=false;
        }
    }
}
```